# How to save and show a pdf file in Android (API 26) in Delphi Berlin 10.2

Tags: android, delphi, pdf

Please,

I read a pdf file from a Blob field using restful server in Embarcadero Berlin 10.2.

In my APP, I code it to TmemoryStream var and I save it using FileStream, like this:

```
FileStream := TFileStream.Create(MyFilePDF, fmCreate);
FileStream.CopyFrom(PDFMemoryStream, PDFMemoryStream.Size);
```

My problem:

Now, I want to show this PDF file in my APP (Android), but I don't know where(which directory) I must save it to read it by Intent(context) .

Thanks in advance. Marcelo.

Comment: Where do you save it now? And why dont you just try?